# send data from sharepoint list to oracle database

Tags: oracle, sharepoint

I want to connect to Oracle Database to send data from SharePoint 2016 list to the Oracle database table. I want to update the Oracle database with SharePoint list item data. every time a new item was added to the list

Answer (score 1):

This can de bone with 2 options
Option - 1 : http://keyurblogs.blogspot.com/2016/06/business-data-connectivity.html

Option  2: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-connect-to-the-oracle-database-using-business-connectivity-services-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010/
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb92fb/connecting-to-oracle-database-through-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using flow or Power automate to schedule on SharePoint list item creation or modification. Flow SharePoint connector is free but Please note that flow Oracle database connector is a premium one :

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_oracle/oracle-database/

Or

A  job can be scheduled in windows, by running an exe using csom for connection to SharePoint and updating Oracle database using Oracle connection provider :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featConnecting.htm

It can be done by .net core also, but currently SharePoint code is not in market.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, we could use Business Connectivity Services( BCS) to connect to external data.

You could refer to this article to connect to an Oracle Database:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff464424(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN